# DB2 Concatenation of varchar columns in join condition

Tags: database, performance, db2

I have a table structured as below

```
partial_id1 | partial_id2 | partial_id3|partial_id4| Name | Address
____________|_____________|____________|___________|______|____________
```

and select query as

```
select 
A.bla1,
A.bla2,
A.bla3
B.Name,
C.Name,
D.Name
from TABLE1 as A 
left join ABOVE_TABLE as B
on 
B.partial_id1||B.partial_id2||B.partial_id3||B.partial_id4=RPAD(A.ID1,11,'0')
left join ABOVE_TABLE as C
on 
C.partial_id1||C.partial_id2||C.partial_id3||C.partial_id4=RPAD(A.ID2,11,'0')
left join ABOVE_TABLE as D
on 
D.partial_id1||D.partial_id2||D.partial_id3||D.partial_id4=RPAD(A.ID3,11,'0')
where A.PK in ('1','2','22')
```

This query is taking too much time. If I remove the left joins it takes <50ms and if I leave them as is, it takes around 4 seconds.

How can I optimize this query? How can I avoid concatenation in join condition?

Comment: In theory, if you could split the `A` ids (`SUBSTR()`, etc), you'd be able to use indices on the `ABOVE_TABLE` side.  Or remove leading zeroes from the concatenated results, and don't use `RPAD()`.  Whether either would be effective would depend on row distribution between tables.  Doing the concatenation in a CTE _might_ help (possibly cause the concatenation to be performed once, as opposed to likely three times).  You might also be able to use knowledge of distribution of values in the id columns to add additional comparisons.  Regardless, fix your db design.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to this is to fix your database design.  Creating a table where you have to concatenate multiple columns to form a key is not a great design for performance.

Note that when you use column functions (concatenate on the left, RPAD on the right) this eliminates the possibility of using indexes (unless you are on DB2 10.5, which added expression-based indexes).

Comment: ...in which case, you have to create the indices first, with the same expression.